# Using .play() to play/pause a video by pressing the enterkey

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-video

I'm searching for a way to start and stop an HTML 5 video in Chrome (I'm using `impress.js`, so it only has to work in Chrome) by pressing the enter key.

I know that it has something to do with the `.play()` function, but I'm rather new to JavaScript.

Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var video = document.getElementById('video-element-id-here');

document.onkeypress = function(e) {
    if ( (e || window.event).keyCode === 13 /* enter key */ ) {
        video.paused ? video.play() : video.pause();
    }
};
```

OP: Please see comments too.

Comment: i'd recommend binding the keypress to the video element, since enter can be pressed on other elements too and that would result in unexpected behaviour

Comment: Good point. I guess it depends on what kind of interaction the OP desires. It is also viable, I think, to check for a falsey `document.activeElement`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myVideo = document.getElementById('vid-id');

document.documentElement.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    var ev = e || window.event; // window.event for IE fallback
    if(ev.keyCode == 13) {
        // toggle play/pause
        if(myVideo.paused) { myVideo.play(); }
        else { myVideo.pause(); }
    }
});
```

**Note:** `keyup` fires only once per press, when a key is released.  `keydown` and `keypress` will fire repeatedly if the user holds down the key.